# Python global variables in recursion get different result

Tags: python, recursion, global

I have this code, which prints `1`:

```py
s = 0

def dfs(n):
    global s
    if n > 10:
        return 0
    s += dfs(n + 1)
    return n

dfs(0)
print(s)
```

If I modify `dfs` like this：

```py
def dfs(n):
    global s
    if n > 10:
        return 0
    i = dfs(n + 1)
    s += i
    return n
```

it will print `55`

I know what is a better way to write the `dfs`. I just want to know why the value of `s` is different after the call of two `dfs`

Comment: @chepner yes my wordings were not correct about the context. Andrej Kesely has explained it really good in the solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Python is interpreted and executed from top to bottom, so in the first version you have:

```py
s += dfs(n + 1)
```

which is exact as:

```py
s = s + dfs(n + 1)
```

So when you do this recursively you have on stack these commands:

```py
s = 0 + dfs(1) # <-- dfs(1) will return 1
s = 0 + dfs(2) # <-- dfs(2) will return 2
...
s = 0 + dfs(9) # <-- dfs(9) will return 9
s = 0 + dfs(10) # <-- dfs(10) will return 10
s = 0 + dfs(11) # <-- dfs(11) will return 0
```

So when you observe, the last step is `s = 0 + 1` and you see the `1` as final result.

---

The second version

```
i = dfs(n + 1)
s += i
```

You assign to `s` after `dfs(n + 1)` is evaluated so you see the final answer `55`

---

NOTE: If you rewrite the first version `s += dfs(n + 1)` to `s = dfs(n + 1) + s` you will see the result `55` too.

Answer (score 4):

When you call it like this:

```
s += dfs(n + 1)
```

The initial value of `s` before the increment is taken *before* it has been modified in the recursive call, so the assignment ends up overwriting whatever change was made in the recursive call.

But when you call it like this:

```
i = dfs(n + 1)
s += i
```

The initial value of `s` is taken *after* it has been modified in the recursive call, so the change in the recursive call is preserved.

In general, recursive functions don't play well with global variables.  Recursive functions need their own separate context.