Nonlocal variable not updated when return value from recursive function is not bound to a variable:
Came across some pattern similar to this for a leetcode problem. Basically, both functions sums a list a recursively using a nonlocal value. The unassigned value only updates res once it seems.
def assigned_sum(l: list[int]):
  res = 0

  def recurse(i: int):
    nonlocal res
    if i >= len(l): 
      return 0

    assigned = recurse(i+1)
    res += assigned
    return l[i]
  
  recurse(-1)
  return res

def rvalue_sum(l: list[int]):
  res = 0
  
  def recurse(i: int):
    nonlocal res
    if i >= len(l): 
      return 0

    res += recurse(i+1)
    return l[i]
  
  recurse(-1)
  return res

test = [1,2,3,4,5]
f"expected={sum(test)}, lvalue={assigned_sum(test)}, rvalue={rvalue_sum(test)}"

When thrown into colab, I get 'expected=15, lvalue=15, rvalue=1'

res += recurse(i+1) The initial value of  res is taken before it gets modified in the recursive call, so the assignment ends up overwriting whatever changes were made in the recursive calls.

@JohnGordon there was recently a question about this exact issue... can't seem to find it

@juanpa.arrivillaga https://stackoverflow.com/q/78240642/494134

The difference can be seen more clearly between these two variants:
(a):
res = res + recurse(i+1)

and (b):
res = recurse(i+1) + res

For your test run, (a) will return 1, while (b) will return the intended 15.
The difference is caused by the moment when the value of res is taken: before the recursive call or after.
If it is taken before the recursive call, it will always be 0. This is because the assignment to res only happens when unwinding out of recursion, not when entering it. So by consequence, all the reading of res that happens at each recursion level, happens before any assignment to res. Then when all the assignments happen to res, they each overwrite the earlier results: 0 + 5, then 0 + 4, then 0 + 3, ... until 0 + 1 which is the final value that is assigned to res.
In the correct version, the value of res is read when unwinding out of recursion, so that means we read the value of res after it has been updated by the recursive call, and so we assign to res: 1 + 0, 2 + 1, 3 + 3, 4 + 6, and finally 5 + 10.
